# Postgres ECPG char[] vs. VARCHAR[]

Tags: postgresql, ecpg

We are using ECPG and host variables to connect to a postgres database.  We're trying to understand when to use `char[]` vs `VARCHAR[]` as our host binding variable.  The documentation doesn't provide any pros/cons or use-cases.

For example:

Given column

```
x VARCHAR (10)
```

Why would I use

```
EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
 char theX[10];
EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;
cout << theX;
```

vs. say

```
EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
 VARCHAR theX[10];
EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;
cout << theX.arr;
```

Thanks!

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ecpg-variables.html

Comment: Of course the documentation does not have anything as what to use depends completely on your intended use. The main difference is char[] defines an array which can contain many values, varchar defined a scalar which contains a single value. Besides the dictum: Never use *char* data type. In this case use varchar[] if you want multiple values.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question.  I've updated the question to be very specific.  Thanks

Comment: I *think* that link refers to database types?  I'm concerned with host variables.

Comment: @a_horse_without_name The type of your C variable is different from the database data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not matter which type you use in C. As [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ecpg-variables.html#ECPG-VARIABLES-TYPE-MAPPING) describes, the difference is that `VARCHAR` is a struct that also contains the length of the string, while `char` is the normal null-terminated C string.

If you need the length, `VARCHAR` might be more convenient.